# How can I give an image a black opaque overlay?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I was busy with a project and thought it would be cool if I could add a black opacity to my pictures but the problem is that I cannot get it to work. I have tried to put the image in the div and than give it a opacity and I have tried it with putting the image in the CSS but no of those could I get to work.

Does anyone of you know how to fix my problem?

This is the HTML that I used for it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>project</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="stage">
            <div class="block" id="begin"></div>
            <div class="block" id="project"></div>
            <div class="block" id="dave"></div>
            <div class="block" id="marjolein"></div>
            <div class="block" id="steef_pieter"></div>
            <div class="block" id="odin"></div>
            <div class="block" id="end"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}


#stage {
    height: 800px; width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll; position: fixed;
}

.block {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

#begin { background: #000 ; opacity: 0.4; background-image: url("../images/begin.jpg"); }

#project {kground-image: url("../images/odin.jpg"); }

#dave { background-image: url("../images/backend.jpg"); }

#marjolein {background-image: url("../images/x.jpg"); }

#steef_pieter {background-image: url("../images/backend.jpg"); }

#odin {background-image: url("../images/odin.jpg");}

#end {background-image: url("../images/end.jpg"); }
```

I have also put it on a random website from me if that helps?
[Website where the project is on](http://cocstats.eu/project/)

It would be really awesome if someone knows the answer because I have tried it but I'm stuck at this moment.

Comment: What is "black opacity"?

Comment: I guess you are looking for [RGBA](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give your container black background or use css filter:

```
#stage {
  background-color: black;
}

#begin {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oravdmxe/

or

```
#begin {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

(use appropriate prefixes for other browsers)

Comment: this does not work on IE, neither earlier versions of Firefox(just latest 35) according to [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter)

Comment: First one - giving an image div opacity and placing it inside the black background div should work with all browsers in last 5 years. This is what I  use when I need to do something like this.

Comment: I was referring to filter only sorry.

Comment: Maybe someone reads it in 5 years when filter will be better supported ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "black opacity" on a image (depending on how you describe it).

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #000;
}

img {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out
}

img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this put a div with black backround infront of the image with an `opacity` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/k2n7dzuc/)

```css
img{
    position:absolute;
}

.box{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    background:rgba(68,68,67,.8);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/300/301">
    <div class="box"></div>
```